# PHP Mail not working when redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a contact form for my website and I am having slight problems. It works fine when not using location and I get an email but when using location I do not get an email when entering the form.

How can I redirect and get the email at the same time?

HTML:

```html
 <div class="contact-form">
  <div class="contact-form-container">
   <form novalidate action="index.php" method="POST">
    <label id="label-0">Position</label>
    <select name="position_form">
     <option value="collaboration_partner">Samarbetspartner</option>
     <option value="youth_organization">Ungdomsorginisation</option>
     <option value="young_enterprise">Ung Företagsamhet</option>
     <option value="work_group">Arbetsgrupp</option>
     <option value="school">Skola</option>
     <option value="volunteer_trainee">Volontär/Praktikant</option>
     <option value="charity">Välgörenhet</option>
     <option value="sponsor">Sponsor</option>
     <option value="other">Annat</option>
    </select>

    <label id="label-1">Namn</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Namn" type="text">

    <label id="label-2">Email Adress</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Adress">

    <label id="label-3">Meddelande</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Meddelande"></textarea>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="SKICKA">
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

PHP:

```html
<?php

$to = "random@protonmail.com";
$subject = "Kontakta Oss - Senaste Meddelande";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$position_form = $_POST["position_form"];
$message = $_POST["message"];



$body = <<<EMAIL

Namn:
$name

Email:
$email

Position:
$position_form

Meddelande:
$message

EMAIL;

$header = "from: kontakt@example.com";
header('Location: http://example.com/redirecthere.php');
exit();

if($_POST){
 mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
}
?>
```

Comment: Exactly how do you think your mail() call would EVER get executed since you have `exit()` beforehand?

Comment: Maybe if you move the header related code to the end of the script....

Comment: Thanks guys, new to this, I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your php file this way:

```
<?php

$to = "random@protonmail.com";
$subject = "Kontakta Oss - Senaste Meddelande";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$position_form = $_POST["position_form"];
$message = $_POST["message"];



$body = <<<EMAIL

Namn:
$name

Email:
$email

Position:
$position_form

Meddelande:
$message

EMAIL;

$header = "from: kontakt@example.com";


if($_POST){
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    header('Location: http://example.com/redirecthere.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

I hope this help you.

by the way I suggest you look for transactional email services like Mailgun, Sendgrid among others.

Comment: Thank you very much. What a realised was that the first answer did not work properly, but this did. Just confirmed your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `mail` function is called (in fact, it's never called) after the `header('Location`. Even if you remove the `header` it wouldn't send mail because there's an `exit` function called before you get the `if`.

Remove the `exit` and move the `header` to the end of the file

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit: Never mind, it did work. Thank you very much. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: I am very grateful that I found Stackoverflow, it has been an amazing help. The fact that I got an answer in less than six minutes, an answer that would have taken hours to understand otherwise. Cheers.